# SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed on a REAL field

Tags: android, sqlite, null, android-sqlite, nan

I received a Crash report on a piece of code that usually works.

The exception is launched in the insertOrThrow and is: "Exception android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: HISTORY.altitude (code 1299)".

All field are declared in the Table as NOT NULL, in particular the HISTORY.altitude field is declared as "REAL NOT NULL"

I cannot understand how is possible that it is NULL, since I fill it few lines over the insert command.

Anyone has an idea of how it is possible?

```
synchronized public void addSample( long time, int method, float altitude, int accuracy )
{
    ...
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        long day = new TimeUtils.Day(time).getMillis();
        cv.put(MetaData.COLUMN_DAY, day);
        cv.put(MetaData.COLUMN_TIME, time);
        cv.put(MetaData.COLUMN_ALTITUDE, altitude);
        cv.put(MetaData.COLUMN_METHOD, method);
        cv.put(MetaData.COLUMN_ACCURACY, accuracy);

        long id = latestSample.mId;
        id = mDb.insertOrThrow(MetaData.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);  // <--- Here crash
    ...
}
```

Here the code used to define the table:

```
/* Inner class that defines the table contents */
public static abstract class MetaData implements BaseColumns
{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "HISTORY";
    public static final String COLUMN_DAY = "day";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
    public static final String COLUMN_ALTITUDE = "altitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_METHOD = "method";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCURACY = "accuracy";
}

private static final String SQL_CREATE_HISTORY_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + MetaData.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                MetaData._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                MetaData.COLUMN_DAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                MetaData.COLUMN_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                MetaData.COLUMN_ALTITUDE + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
                MetaData.COLUMN_METHOD + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                MetaData.COLUMN_ACCURACY + " INTEGER NOT NULL " +
                " );\n" +
        "CREATE INDEX " + MetaData.COLUMN_METHOD + " ON " + MetaData.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MetaData.COLUMN_METHOD + ");\n" +
        "CREATE INDEX " + MetaData.COLUMN_DAY + " ON " + MetaData.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MetaData.COLUMN_DAY + ");\n" +
        "CREATE INDEX " + MetaData.COLUMN_TIME + " ON " + MetaData.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MetaData.COLUMN_TIME + ");";
```

Comment: Your altitude value is null

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin A `float` value cannot be `null`. But it's probably NaN.

Comment: @CL. Yes, it can be if is a `Long` object at its base. Had that kind of error some time ago.

Comment: No when it's primitive float, as it is (float altitude).

Comment: Yes, it's a primitive float and cannot be null. @CL I did a fast test and if I insert NaN I get a NOT NULL constraint exception, so it's probably the reason... Thanks. If you add an answer I can accept it and so close the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite does not allow floating-point values that are NaN, and treats them as NULL.
So if your `float` value ends up being NaN somehow, it will violate the NOT NULL constraint.